# How can database load large data table into memory?

Tags: in-memory-database

I'm figuring out about in-memory databases. Some articles said that an in-memory database is a database that keeps the whole dataset in RAM.

What does that mean? It means that each time you query a database or update data in a database, you only access the main memory. I’m confused about how database keeps the whole dataset in RAM?

I'm understanding that when I do `select * from table1`, in-memory database automatically load this table into memory and after this I'm able to use table very fast.

Now assume that I just have 8GB RAM and a very large table (100TB), how can database load large data table into memory?

Comment: It can't, obviously.  In-memory databases are only good for modestly-sized data sets that fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. An in memory database is where your entire dataset must fit in ram.  You can get servers with 256gb of ram which allows many datasets to comfortable fit in ram

Paging things in and out of memory is what a regular database does.